# How to run default behavior after the animation complete?

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLT8j/)

Suppose if I use like this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $(this)
  .animate({ left: -10 })
  .animate({ left: 10 })
  .animate({ left: -10 })
  .animate({ left: 10 })
  .animate({ left: 0 });
});
```

Then the default behavior of the link would be triggered first and after going back to the page the animation would appear.

So, if I use like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this)
  .animate({ left: -10 })
  .animate({ left: 10 })
  .animate({ left: -10 })
  .animate({ left: 10 })
  .animate({ left: 0 });
});
```

Then the animation would run but default behavior would be stopped.

But I would like to assign the default behavior of the link after the animation completes.

I have tried much more something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this)
   .animate({ left: -10 })
   .animate({ left: 10 })
   .animate({ left: -10 })
   .animate({ left: 10 })
   .animate({ left: 0 });
   return e; //return e.target; //return e.type;
});
```

So, How can I register the default action after preventing the default?

Is there anything something like `e.runDefault()` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    _link = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this)
       .animate({ left: -10 })
       .animate({ left: 10 })
       .animate({ left: -10 })
       .animate({ left: 10 })
     .animate({ left: 0 }, function(){
         window.location.href = _link;
     });
 });
```